# How to handle 'open-sourcing' your application, when it uses a personal API key?

Tags: open-source, api-key

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to open-source an application that uses API keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983990/how-to-open-source-an-application-that-uses-api-keys)

I'm creating an application that uses a personal API key. How can I open source the application?

Possible Duplicate:
[How to open-source an application that uses API keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983990/how-to-open-source-an-application-that-uses-api-keys)

I guess now my question is, which is a good option to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the API key a configuration item so that it can be specified by the person using the code rather than having it hard-coded within the source.

Answer (score 1):

Mask the key in the application with instructions that the user should get his own key. Would be best if this configurable from a config file or UI.

It may also be good to have a screen demo of the application, so the target audience knows how it is suppose to behave when they put in their own key.