# Distributing binaries of an open source application using an API key

Tags: api-key

I'm developing an application that uses an API key, and I am considering making it open source (probably under the GPLv3).

I've seen [How to open-source an application that uses API keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1983990/1917313), and am considering designing so that if the API key is provided during compilation (using an included C++ header file), it will be used by the application. Otherwise it will have a first-run wizard and settings panel to set the API key at runtime.

I am planning on distributing my application in the Ubuntu Software Center. Is it possible to distribute binaries of the application with my own API key compiled into it, or would this break the GPL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote to the FSF, and here is their response:

> Given the API key and the source code, people who receive the source
>   code of your software should be able to compile the same binary they got
>   from you and use it in the same way. From your description this seems to
>   be the case.
>
> They should also be free not to use your API key or web service, but to
>   modify the software and connect it to a web service of their own choice
>   or design with their own API keys. I'm unfamiliar with the web service/s
>   in question and therefore I don't know if this is relevant to your
>   specific situation.
>
> I hope this answer is of help. Please feel free to write back if you
>   have any further questions.
>
> --
>   I am not a lawyer, the above is not legal advice
>
> Regards, Yoni Rabkin